# plotly relayout event data in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-html

I can't figure how to use the plotly js data from the plotly_relayout event in Dart.  I've put a breakpoint in the js console, and my data looks like this:

[js_console_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sORrA.png)

How do I access the xaxis.range[0] in Dart?  It is not a simple map.

Thank you,
Tony

Answer (score 1):

After I restarted the DDC, `print(data["xaxis.range[0]"]);` returned the correct value.

Comment: This is the answer, wow. Ty.